# Deploying ASP.Net site on iis 7 - shows iis 7 screen

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, iis-7, splash-screen

So I'm trying to deploy an ASP.Net MVC 3 application to a web server running Windows server 2008 R2. What I've attempted to do is use iis 7 to handle setup, and I've deployed by using xcopy. When I try to access the site, all I receive is the iis 7 splashpage. I've ran aspnet_regiis and two other sites are running via iis which while not set up by me are to the best of my knowledge set up in the same way using nearly identical settings.

I was hoping someone might be familiar with the issue and could point my in the right direction, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You should check that .NET MVC is installed on your server, the binaries for it are sometimes missing from default .NET installations. An easy way to check this is to go to your site, look at the "Handler Mappings" feature, verify that the MVC HttpHandler is listed. It should be if your web.config is set up properly or if you manually added it to the list.

Another way to get answers would be to ask this question on the Ops-oriented sister site of StackOverflow: https://serverfault.com/